How do I correctly set dimensions for Cloudwatch alarms in Terraform?
I want to create a Cloudwatch alarm for Memory Utilisation across an ASG.
This is the SQL query I want to replicate in Terraform:
SELECT AVG(mem_used_percent)
FROM SCHEMA(CWAgent, AutoScalingGroupName,ImageId,InstanceId,InstanceType)
WHERE AutoScalingGroupName = 'my-asg-name'

This is my current Terraform code:
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "memory_utilization_high" {
  alarm_name          = "HighMemoryUtilizationAcrossASG"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = 3
  threshold           = 80
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.asg_alerts.arn]
  treat_missing_data  = "breaching"

  metric_query {
    id          = "e1"
    expression  = "AVG([m1])"
    label       = "Average Memory Utilisation across ASG"
    return_data = "true"
  }

  metric_query {
    id = "m1"
    metric {
      metric_name = "mem_used_percent"
      namespace   = "CWAgent"
      period      = 300
      stat        = "Average"
      unit        = "Percent"

      dimensions = {
        AutoScalingGroupName = var.asg_name
        InstanceId           = ""
        InstanceType         = ""
        ImageId              = ""
      }
    }
  }
}

I get this Terraform error:
error ValidationError: 3 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'metrics.2.member.metricStat.metric.dimensions.2.member.value' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value '' at 'metrics.2.member.metricStat.metric.dimensions.3.member.value' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value '' at 'metrics.2.member.metricStat.metric.dimensions.4.member.value' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1

I have tried removing these dimensions:
InstanceId = ""
InstanceType = ""
ImageId = ""

and Terraform is happy with it but Cloudwatch doesn't show any metrics. The SQL query at the top though does what I need.
Anybody has any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

I always struggle getting the alarm dimensions right in Terraform. It's a bit of a guessing game. What I usually do is create the alarm I want first in the AWS web UI, and once that is working I then either import that into Terraform, or just copy the dimension values from that alarm into Terraform and delete the Alarm that I created manually. By going through the web UI you will be able to browse the available metrics and have the dimensions populated for you.

Thanks @MarkB. Through the UI, I'm able to create the alarm with no problem. The issue is with creating that same alarm with Terraform. I had avoided going the import route but it looks like I might end up doing that :) I tried copying the UI dimension values in Terraform with no luck. I wish Terraform supported SQL queries directly. Thanks a lot for your input.

You can't actually create alerts using SQL queries can you? I don't think you can do that even through the AWS web UI.

I meant SQL queries or expressions for metric queries, not alerts themselves.

Here, metric query is just an attribute of the Alarm. Terraform can only support what the AWS API supports: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html It looks like you can actually use SQL queries (actually called a Metrics Insights query) to create alarms, if you look at the example at the very bottom of that page. You pass the query in the metric expression attribute. You should try that in Terraform.
